# bash: ./lmcrypt: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

While trying to run an executable called `lmcrypt` on a 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS system, I'm getting the following error:

```
$ ./lmcrypt
-bash: ./lmcrypt: No such file or directory
```

As far as I can tell, the file is a valid 64-bit executable:

```
$ file ./lmcrypt
./lmcrypt: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

For comparison:

```
file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=d0bc0fb9b3f60f72bbad3c5a1d24c9e2a1fde775, stripped
```

What am I missing?

Edit: `readelf -l lmcrypt` returns the following output

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x40512c
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001c0 0x00000000000001c0  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000400200 0x0000000000400200
                 0x000000000000001a 0x000000000000001a  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000fcaf4 0x00000000000fcaf4  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x00000000000fd000 0x00000000006fd000 0x00000000006fd000
                 0x0000000000009219 0x000000000000d808  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x00000000000fd788 0x00000000006fd788 0x00000000006fd788
                 0x0000000000000220 0x0000000000000220  RW     8
  NOTE           0x000000000000021c 0x000000000040021c 0x000000000040021c
                 0x0000000000000020 0x0000000000000020  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00000000000da9c0 0x00000000004da9c0 0x00000000004da9c0
                 0x0000000000004ae4 0x0000000000004ae4  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     8

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .textidx .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .fnp_dir .fnp_marker .bss
   04     .dynamic
   05     .note.ABI-tag
   06     .eh_frame_hdr
   07
```

Comment: What does `readelf -l lmcrypt` return for the interpreter? Does the specific interpreter exist on your system?

Comment: @doneal24 I've added the output to the description

Comment: Second part of my question was does `/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3` exist on your system. I don't think so for an Ubuntu 16.04 setup. My guess is that the binary was compiled on a different distribution, perhaps CentOS.

Comment: @doneal24 no `/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3` does not exist on this system

Comment: `/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3` is provided by the package `redhat-lsb-core` **:** CentOS, RHEL, Fedora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/60238/918140), it looks like you should install the `lsb` package:

```
sudo apt install lsb
```

This should give you the required package on `/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3` (just tested it on Ubuntu 16.04.7 and it does).

Answer (score 1):

As an answer so that this question does not get orphaned. The elf interpreter for the binary does not exist on the target system. The interpreter exists by default on REL-compatible systems but not on Ubuntu 16.04. Using `apt-get install lsb` might help but I cannot verify since the OS is already past end-of-life.